# Question about difference of getween "lane" and "line"

Tags: word-meaning

> Left turns–To make a left turn, drive close to the center divider **line** or into the left turn **lane**. Begin signaling about 100 feet before the turn. Look over your left shoulder and reduce your speed. Stop behind the limit line. Look left, then right, then left again, and make the turn when it is safe. When you turn left, do not turn too soon and “cut the corner” of the lane belonging to the vehicles coming towards you.

I would also be greatful if you could tell me what a "center divider line" is?

Answer (score 7):

In terms of roads, the *lane* is the area of the road usually demarcated by *lines*. On a normal 2 lane, 2 way road, there will usually be a broken line between the two lanes - this is the divider line. One lane goes in one direction, the other lane goes in the other direction.

You also have multi-lane roads - highways, motorways, autobahns etc. Here there are usually 3 *lanes* either side of the divider (often called a *median strip* because it is not just a line). Each lane is divided by *lines*.

I've made a lovely diagram because I'm just nice like that:

[image]